# What's the best practice to transfer much information to another class at instantiation?

Tags: c#, wpf, theory

I have two different WPF projects. The first one should start a new instance of the main window of the second project.

The class of project one, which should initiate the main window, is a VM in the MVVM pattern and provides useful information for the second project.

Based on the information the behavior of the second project changes. Let's say I have to transfer 10 variables and there are 5 different behaviors of the project, which are determined by those variables.

The requirement is to instantiate the main window with only one constructor.
It would be pretty bad if I had only one constructor with 10 variables and 5 if statements for every possible behavior.

What is the accepted way to handle such a problem?

Comment: Can't you write a "DetermineState" method, and pass the result of that method into the constructor of project 2? (for example, pass the "ProjectTwoState" emum value)

Comment: You've not explained enough. For example do you always need these 10 variables? In which case passing in a class with 10 properties seems kind of obvious. What pattern is there to the data, behaviours and if statements - are they perhaps mutually exclusive.... Or what? Maybe you could use inheritance and pass in a banana or apple or pineapple, all of which inherit from fruit and override an extractjuice method. We can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure in what way you're instantiating the second window while passing these arguments to a constructor, but when you want to pass a lot of information between objects, I'd suggest wrapping your parameters into a `class` or `struct` that both projects recognize. This way, you're only passing one parameter as opposed to 10 or more.

This way, regardless of whether you're reading these parameters from a file or passing them from the first application as arguments, the constructor will only require that one parameter.